# Calculating mutual information between two classifiers for a fixed dataset

Tags: math

After searching the web, I have no answer for my question. There are some formulas that, for example, can calculate the entropy between two classifiers.

How can I calculate the mutual information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider we have two random variables X and Y . The mutual information between these two statistical variables is defined by `I(X,Y) = H(X) + H(Y) − H(X,Y)` where `H(X)` is the
entropy of variable `X` , `H(X,Y)` is the joint entropy of both variables, and `H(Y|X) = H(X,Y) − H(X)` is the conditional
entropy that measures the uncertainty of variable `Y` given the value of variable `X`. The `MI` between these two variables measure the amount of uncertainty reduction for one variable given the value of the other variable.